# Equivalence of following if(root == null) return root; in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am solving leetcode tree problems in Kotlin (new in Kotlin and switching from  JAVA). I was trying to figure out best equivalence of following JAVA code in Kotlin:

```
if(root == null) return root;
```

E.g.

I have converted following code :

```
public TreeNode invertTree(TreeNode root) {

        if(root == null) return root;

        TreeNode left = invertTree(root.left);
        TreeNode right = invertTree(root.right);
        if(root != null) {
            root.left = right;
            root.right = left;
        }

        return root;
    }
```

to following Kotlin code :

```
fun invertTree(root: TreeNode?): TreeNode? {
        return root ?: root
        var left = invertTree(root.left)
        var right = invertTree(root.right)

        root.right = left
        root.left = right

        return root;
    }
```

But I get below error :

```
Line 14: Char 35: error: only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type TreeNode?
        var left = invertTree(root.left)
```

Interesting part is that if you use `if(root == null) return root` , you do not get above error.

Comment: Kotlin equivalence of Java is exactly the same code above just without semicolon. And btw if root is null you're returning null, I mean like why?

Comment: Base condition for recursive call.

Comment: Can you post any surrounding code?  There may be ways to shorten it, but we can't tell from that one line alone.

Comment: alternatively, you can do this
```return root ?: root```
but why null check and then returning the same.

Comment: Added for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach is using pattern matching avoiding null. You can create a sealed class defining all the possibilities of your type. In the case below, you can represent `null` with NotANumber, for example.

```kotlin
sealed class Expr
data class Const(val number: Double) : Expr()
data class Sum(val e1: Expr, val e2: Expr) : Expr()
object NotANumber : Expr()

fun xyz(expression: Expr) = when(expression) {
    is Const -> ...
    is Sum -> ...
    is NotANumber -> 
    ...
}
```

In your specific case you can define "null" nodes like NotANode or EmptyNode or whatever you might want.